# How do I only apply padding to the text in a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Without padding I get this result:

[image: no padding]

With something like this

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0), child: TextField())
```

I get the following result:

[image: with padding]

It might be a bit hard to see, but you only have to look at the red badge across the edge to realise what I mean.

I would like to only move the text with my padding, but in reality the whole `TextField` has the padding applied, i.e. that the underline moves with the padding, but I would like to have the underline still go across the whole view, that only the text inside the `TextField` is affected by the padding.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

To apply the padding to the content of the `TextField`. You can apply the

> contentPadding property of ItemDecoration at decoration property of TextField.

Like this:

```dart
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter Something',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You also might want to consider `isDense: true` in the `InputDecoration` for a more precise padding that is smaller than the default.

Comment: @Giraldi isDense:true really helps.

Answer (score 27):

Works for me:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10), //Change this value to custom as you like
    isDense: true, // and add this line
    hintText: 'User Name',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFFF00),
  )),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  style: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xFFF00),
      fontSize: 14),
  maxLines: 1,
)
```

Comment: isDense is important. The default vertical padding is gone now. thanks

Comment: i apply isDense= true.but still bottom padding not set as i set.

Comment: thanks for "isDense" hint! Saved time :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to apply uneven, vertical padding to each side of the text inside the TextField, you'll have to first set textAlignVertical to TextAlignVertical.top.

If you don't do this, the largest top/bottom padding will apply to both the top and bottom of the text. I'm guessing this is because the TextField text is always centered horizontally.

```
TextField(
        controller: model.captionController,
        maxLines: null,
        minLines: 8,
        maxLength: 200,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
        decoration: PostFilledField('Add a caption...').copyWith(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( 8, 0,  8, 90.0),
          isDense: true
        ),
        style: PostSmallText(),
      ),
```

Comment: hi what is PostFilledField?

Comment: That is probably an extended class from InputDecoration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the combination of "contentPadding" and "isDesnse" to achieve your requirements.

```
 TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Something',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                isDense: true,
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating TextField as children widget in Column/Row widget it may not work if you set padding/content padding to textfield in root Widget.

Make sure always setting content padding based on your requirement at TextField level using **InputDecoration**

here is simple snippet for setting up padding for TextField content

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Title', 
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
 )
```

Result:

[image]