# Is there any way to customize text field without wrap with Container in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: Example of TextField - flutter]

I can customize a TextField wrap it with a Container. Like i can set margin property.
But is there any way to customize the TextField without wrapping it with Container ?

***More specifically:***
Can i set the margin/padding attribute on TextField ?

Comment: is the [InputDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)  not enough ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098175/3279156 , please check this for more about padding

Comment: @RaoufRahiche yes, its more than enough what i want. I just find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @sreeramu Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [InputDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding : new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Please enter a search term'
  ),
);
```

Comment: I wanted to know how can i set the margin and padding property of TextField.

Comment: use the contentPadding  property you can't set the margin directly but you can set the padding

Comment: Yes, i just find it. But there is no contentMargin property for margin. And thats why i need to wrap my TextField with Container. And then set the margin property.

Comment: yes i think for the maring you have to wrap it inside a Container